# Unable to pull latest code from git on ubuntu server

Tags: git, ubuntu, server

I'm trying to pull changes from my git branch onto an Ubuntu server. For some reason, I'm getting this error when trying to pull:

```
ubuntu@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx:/var/www/html/prod/dist$ git pull
Username for 'https://github.com': my_name
Password for 'https://my_name@github.com':
remote: Counting objects: 1082, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (96/96), done.
fatal: Unable to create temporary file '/var/www/html/prod/dist/.git/objects/pack/tmp_pack_XXXXXX': Permission denied
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Any thoughts on why this is occuring? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The user you're executing the command as (`ubuntu` judging from your prompt), doesn't have permission to create the temporary file in question.

You can inspect the current permissions of the `pack` directory by running the following command:

```
$ ls -ld .git/objects/pack
drwxr-xr-x 2 chuckx chuckx 4096 May 28 22:51 .git/objects/pack
```

Based on the results you can decide what to do. Some options include:

- run the command as a user with permissions
- recursively change the ownership of the directory to give the `ubuntu` user permission to write (i.e. `chown -R ubuntu .git`

Comment: Thank you @chuckx - I was owned by root and I just ran my pull command with sudo

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have permission problems locally to write inside **/var/www/html/prod/dist/.git/**. Check that you are using a user that has RW access over there.